# groovy change calendar date

Tags: java, groovy, jira

I am trying to get an output from `cal` inside the switch statement but it is giving me the current date, what am I doing wrong? An explanation would be much appreciated too. Thank you.

```
import static java.util.Calendar.*
import java.sql.Timestamp.*

every = 4 //testing
period = 'weeks(s)' //testing

if (every && period){

def cal = Calendar.instance
def addTime
addTime = cal.time
    switch (period) {
        case "day(s)":
        cal[DATE]  = cal[DATE] + every
        addTime = cal.time
        break
        case "weeks(s)":
        cal[DATE]  = cal[DATE] + every*7
        addTime = cal.time
        break
        case "month(s)":
        cal[DATE]  = cal[MONTH] + every
        addTime = cal.time
        break
        case "year(s)":
        cal[YEAR]  = cal[YEAR] + every
        addTime = cal.time
        break
        case "day of the month":
        cal[MONTH]  = cal[MONTH] + 1
        cal[DATE] = every
        addTime = cal.time
        break
    }

java.sql.Timestamp newTimestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(addTime.getTime());
dueDate = newTimestamp
}
println dueDate
```

This script for instance does the job e.g., my `dueDate` is updated correctly but it is hard coded in `newTimestamp` line, so how can I implement the above switch inside the code below?

```
//import com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager
//import com.atlassian.jira.issue.CustomFieldManager
//import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue
//import com.atlassian.jira.issue.customfields.CustomFieldType
//import com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.CustomField
import java.sql.Timestamp;

//MutableIssue myIssue = issue

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
// set due date to: current date + 30 days
Timestamp mydueDate = new Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis()+ 2592000000);
println mydueDate

//myIssue.setDueDate(mydueDate);
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking about.

Comment: switch statement is supposed to change the duedate based on the condition eg. In above the week(s) is true so I would expect to get today's date + 2 weeks in duedate

Comment: My output is in January, 2016. It works ok.

Comment: This is strange as I get same output from groovy console but when added to JIRA as a script i get current date every time. Thank you for helping anyway.

Comment: @Opal just added the working code can you have a look ?

Comment: I see, it works ok. Is there still any problem?

Answer (score 1):

This was the actual way to go about it so JIRA would stop complaining.

```
import com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager 
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.CustomFieldManager
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.customfields.CustomFieldType
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.CustomField
import java.sql.Timestamp;


def every, period
if (cfValues['Every']){
    every = cfValues['Every'] as int

}
if (cfValues["Period"]){
    period = cfValues["Period"]
}

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
if (every && period){
    switch (period) {
        case "day(s)":
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, every)
        break
        case "week(s)":
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, every*7)
        break
        case "month(s)":
        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, every)
        break
        case "year(s)":
        cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, every)
        break
        case "day of the month":
        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1)
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, every)
        break
    }
}

MutableIssue myIssue = issue

Timestamp mydueDate = new Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis());

myIssue.setDueDate(mydueDate);

//copy the parent issue summary
issue.summary = sourceIssue.summary

//delete the links and attachements
checkLink = {link -> false};
checkAttachment = {attachment -> false}
```